# Pinpoint strange text at initiation of SSH session

Tags: ssh, terminal, opensuse, sshd

On my OpenSUSE 13.1 (Gnome 3) system, whenever I start a SSH session, somewhere in the initialization, the terminal outputs some strange lines.

```
Last login: Sat Nov 29 00:00:00 2014 from [HOSTNAME]
NAME=openSUSE
VERSIONuser@host:~>
```

Now, `Last login: ...`, I understand. But, why is it printing that `NAME\VERSION` string? I would expect it to output the following:

```
Last login: Sat Nov 29 00:00:00 2014 from [HOSTNAME]
user@host:~>
```

In fact, the output of SSH sessions to all of my other OpenSUSE machines matches this output I would expect.

I put echo statements at the beginning and end of the `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` scripts to see if the text came from those, but those echos output after the `NAME\VERSION` string, indicating that the strange output comes earlier than those *profile* scripts. Also, the strange output matches the beginning of the `/etc/os-release` file, though I don't know why the terminal would be printing that file's contents.

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL
```

So, why would my SSH sessions begin like this or how would I trace this quirk down?

Comment: Under Ubuntu you get the `motd`: Message of the Day. It is likely those scripts that generate that kind of output.

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/motd`? Do you also get this on a local login, or with `su -`?

Comment: I don't get the text at local login or any SU session. The MOTD file had the text in there (see [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171724/13308)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Message of the Day* file (`/etc/motd`) had the strange text in there. I wonder what put that there.

I deleted the MOTD file and now my sessions no longer begin with the strange text.

Answer (score 0):

I'd turn up the logging level for the SSH Daemon via the configuration file, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Typically this section of the configuration file:

```
# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO
```

Uncomment the `LogLevel` section and restart SSH service. This should show you where those messages are coming from if they're related to SSH.